# DAX Approximate Match - Earliest date before a certain date (Power Pivot)

Tags: dax, lookup, powerpivot

In the sales_tbl I want to fetch cost from the cost_tbl by identifying the value which is most recent value starting from and including 2023-01-01.

**sales_tbl**

| ProductID | Cost (to be fetched from cost_tbl) |
| --- | --- |
| 0004087 | 37 |
| 6202188 | 283 |

**cost_tbl**

| ProductID | Cost Valid From | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0004087 | 2022-11-10 | 25 |
| 0004087 | 2022-12-10 | 37 |
| 0004087 | 2023-01-03 | 56 |
| 0004087 | 2023-01-04 | 65 |
| 6202188 | 2021-04-12 | 243 |
| 6202188 | 2022-12-02 | 256 |
| 6202188 | 2022-12-10 | 276 |
| 6202188 | 2023-01-01 | 283 |

I've found some solutions but I've not been able to alter those to work for my case.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a calculated column in the sale_tbl using DAX.

`````
````
Cost = 
VAR TargetDate = DATE(2023, 1, 1)
VAR ProductID = sales_tbl[ProductID]

RETURN
CALCULATE (
    MAX ( cost_tbl[Cost] ),
    FILTER (
        cost_tbl,
        cost_tbl[ProductID] = ProductID
            && cost_tbl[Valid From] >= TargetDate
            && cost_tbl[Valid From] <= EARLIER(sales_tbl[Valid From])
    )
)
````
`````

This establishes 2 variables, TargetDate as 2023-01-1 and ProductID to store the current row's ProductID from sales_tbl.  Then it uses Calculate to find the maximum cost, filtered by the previous conditions provided within the Filter function.

The Filter function ensures the cost_tbl row has the same ProductID as teh current row, the ValidFrom dates is >= the TargetDate and the Valid From date is less than or equal to the current row's Valid From date in sales_tbl

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However I am unsure how to translate this solution into Power Pivot using variables. Is that something which is possible?

Comment: You should be able to do the same thing.  You'd go Manage/Data under Data Tools then in the Power Pivot window click on the sales_tbl.  In the Home tab in the Power Pivot toolbar click on Calculated Column to create a new calculated column.  Enter the formula from above making whatever adjustments are required relative to column names, etc.